# Sending DataTables to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

How can I send data table to SQL stored procedure as `Table Type` from `.net core` web application when `DataTable` was removed. In `mvc 4` I used to do it like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2]
{                    
   new DataColumn("Id", typeof (int)),
   new DataColumn("Value", typeof (string))
 });

foreach (var l in m.myList)
{
  dt.Rows.Add(l.Id, l.Value);
}
```

**And then I send it as parameter to the stored procedure:**

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedureName", conn))
     {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeTbl", dt);
```

**SQL:**

```
create PROCEDURE  MyStoredProcedureName

    @TypeTbl SqlTalbe READONLY  

    AS
```

What is the equivalent to `DataTable` in `.net Core` ?

Comment: Who told you `DataTable` was removed? https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net?q=DataTable

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1039

Comment: @Tseng honestly speaking, it was once decided to be removed, but added back at last minute due to community voices. The threads can still be found at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?q=Datatable&type=Issues&utf8=✓

Comment: @LexLi: I see. I always use the packagesearch to see if a certain Class is available and in which package it's is available or when I'm unsure

Comment: @Tseng acknowledged. I just want to answer you question :)

Comment: anyway, something is wrong with DataTable - it cannot be declared.